# What is making my HTML select options become bold?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, fonts

I'm building a simple static site that contains some HTML `<select>` tags, and have run into a problem where the options for these dropdowns have inexplicably become bold:

[image]

I've run into this issue before on a more complex site, but at the time put it down to a conflict with the many different frameworks and libraries involved, but that's obviously not the case for a site built with nothing but HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
The HTML is structured like so:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

 <form action="javascript:calculate();" method="post">
        Select the option with
        <select name="select1" class="select1" onchange="document.getElementById('lpd').placeholder=this.value" required>
            <option value="13">Option 1</option>
            <option value="15">Option 2</option>
        </select>
 </form>
```

And below is all of the CSS relevant to these inputs that could potentially be causing the issue:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.5;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
    font: inherit;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
    background-color: unset;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.container {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    padding-top: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}

select {
    padding: 0.2em;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
    margin: 0 0.3em;
}

input {
    padding: 0.3em 0;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

Removing the `font-inherit` line - which comes from [Josh Comeau's CSS reset](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/custom-css-reset/#digit-inherit-fonts-for-form-controls) - seems to "solve" the problem, but also makes all input tags return to their default font sizes. This makes me believe the issue is caused by increasing the size of the inputs, but I can't think why or how to prevent it.

I've also tried targeting the options directly using a workaround like `.select1 *`, but while this works to change attributes like `background-color`, no amount of changing the `font-weight` makes any difference.

#### EDIT:

**I created a [minimal Pen here](https://codepen.io/Kaos-Industries/pen/oNEyxaj) that still reproduces the problem, and have just noticed that the issue isn't present in Chrome. Could it be possible that this is a Firefox bug?**

Comment: Does the `Inter` font have a different system of font weighting? `400` might be "very bold".

Comment: onchange="document.getElementById('lpd').placeholder=this.value" what else is that for look that area. wheres the css of it or what is it doing that might have a bold onchange or font weight. 400 is not a very bold really, also try to put !important I would say

Comment: I tried your exact example on Chrome and FF under Win 11 and don't have the problem you describe. I wonder if there is another piece of CSS involved, something that you have been missing in your code example.

Comment: @Andy No, it's pretty standard and predictable elsewhere on the site it looks on the rest of the site. 400 is actually being applied to the currently selected option as seen in the screenshot, but the inputs in the select's dropdown end up styled in something that looks 700 or bolder, and I don't know what could possibly be setting those.

Comment: @DieterRaber Did you try with the Inter font?

Comment: @Crystal `!important` also doesn't work, and the `lpd` is a different element elsewhere on the page irrelevant to this one, but I tried getting rid of that `onchange` line just in case and as expected it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes @HashimAziz, my code looks like this (sorry, this looks messy in comments):
```
<head>
        [...]
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <style>The CSS you posted</style>
    </head>
    <body class="container"><!--your form -->
    </body>```

Comment: @HashimAziz https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap...... look at the loaded part on your font as well maybe that's where you are having an issue. Maybe its inheriting the parent of the font-family. Try to use a different font on the and see if that makes a different, just another thought.

Comment: I created a minimal Pen here that still reproduces the problem: https://codepen.io/Kaos-Industries/pen/oNEyxaj. I have also just noticed the issue isn't present in Chrome, so you'll have to use Firefox if you want to reproduce. Possible Firefox bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really strange issue that I've never ran into before, but the problem was that I had the font - Inter in this case - locally installed, and for some reason `<select> <option>` elements (at least in Firefox, because the issue wasn't reproducible in Chrome) prefer the locally installed version of the font. Uninstalling the font locally was the only workaround to this I could find, but either way it's a local system issue and not one that affects end users - unless they have the Inter font installed, I suppose. Like I said, a very weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want the select option text to be bold just add this CSS

> select option {
> font-weight: 400 !important;
> }

Comment: Did you try this using Firefox with the Pen I provided in my comment a few hours ago? Solutions like this don't this work.

Comment: `@supports (-moz-appearance:none) {
  option 
  {
  -moz-appearance:none !important;
   font-weight: 400 !important; 
  }
}`

Comment: try this one on the CSS

Comment: If you try your solutions in the [pen](https://codepen.io/Kaos-Industries/pen/oNEyxaj) yourself while using Firefox, you'll see that they don't work.

Comment: I have just tried it out but the text in the option is not actually bold at all, maybe the problem is in your browser

Comment: Did you try it in Firefox like I said?

Comment: yup! just the same, still no problem on my end, try clearing your firefox cache or data

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to change the browser? Here there are no problems with bold.

Maybe you have to clean the cache of the browser. Or inspect how many documents CSS are uploaded, when you open the serve and surf into your web page. Or inspect the select. And see all CSS features and check bold is not assigned.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.5;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
    font: inherit;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
    background-color: unset;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.container {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    padding-top: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}

select {
    padding: 0.2em;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
    margin: 0 0.3em;
}

input {
    padding: 0.3em 0;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

 <form action="javascript:calculate();" method="post">
        Select the option with
        <select name="select1" class="select1" onchange="document.getElementById('lpd').placeholder=this.value" required>
            <option value="13">Option 1</option>
            <option value="15">Option 2</option>
        </select>
<input type="text" id="lpd">
 </form>
```